# Oracle database INTERNAL_USE

Tags: sql, oracle

What does the `INTERNAL_USE` clause in Oracle Database mean? For example in this:

`ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AL32UTF8;`

I've only seen this used in examples and snippets and haven't managed to find any information other than [a vague comment on this thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/2486282) stating that it shouldn't be used by customers and hasn't been documented, but that comment is from 2005 so I'm wondering if anything has changed since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing has changed since 2005.  The clause is undocumented.  It should not be used by customers unless explicitly instructed to do so by Oracle support.

`internal_use` bypasses a host of checks that are in place to prevent you from corrupting the data in your database when you change the character set (among potentially other side-effects that are known and understood only by Oracle).  Customers should not be bypassing those checks on their own.  Unless, of course, they enjoy restoring their database from backups.

Comment: Indeed, I had initially suggested that `csscan/csalter` be used instead but the other party did the above anyway. It's a shame because there's a lot of examples on forums (and SO too) that suggest the above command with `internal_use`.